# Use hard drive instead of RAM in Python

Tags: python, pandas, memory, pydev

I'd like to know if there's a method or a Python Package that can make me use a large dataset without writing it in RAM.

I'm also using pandas for statistical function.

I need to have access on the entire dataset because many statistical functions needs the entire dataset to return credible results.

I'm using PyDev (with interpreter Python 3.4) on LiClipse with Windows 10.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. First off you should read ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic". Try searching for memory mapping in python, pandas and the like.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Give us more details on what you need exactly or accept an answer for what you have got so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could alternatively use [Sframes](https://dato.com/learn/gallery/notebooks/introduction_to_sframes.html), [Dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) for large dataset support or alternatively use pandas and read/iterate in chunks in order to minimise RAM usage.
Also worth having a look at the [blaze](http://blaze.pydata.org/) library

Read in chunks:

```
chunksize = 10 ** 6
for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize):
process(chunk)
```

Comment: OK, thanks but now the problem is different, with Dask i minimized the ram usage but now i will use pandas statistical fuctions and with Dask i can't use all of them. How can i do? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a virtualization of the disk as a large RAM memory you might set up a swap file on the system. The kernel will then automatically swap pages in and out as needed, using heuristics to figure out what pages should be swapped and which should stay on disk.

Comment: Thank you, your suggest is usefull too, there is an easy method to do this in Windows ? Thank you very much